# Common lisp load package from name in string

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'm using mod_lisp along with the modlisp-clisp.lisp file at http://www.fractalconcept.com/fcweb/download/modlisp-clisp.lisp. I want to load different packages based on the server-id field so I can have different sites set up. I was trying to do this with

```
(server-id:fetch-content request)
```

with server-id quoted and unquoted, but it couldn't find the package. Some document-hunting found me find-package, but when I do

```
((find-package server-id):fetch-content request)
```

it says

```
(FIND-PACKAGE SERVER-ID) should be a lambda expression.
```

How can I load a package given the package name as a string?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use different symbols when calling functions, you have to compute them.

```
(funcall (find-symbol (compute-the-name) (compute-the-package))
         arg1 ... argn)
```

Note that both package and symbol names are usually uppercase strings.

```
CL-USER 6 > (funcall (find-symbol "EXPT" "CL") 3 4)
81
```

Note that you should not let the user over the network specify arbitrary functions and arguments which are then called without error checking.

Answer (score 0):

[Common Lisp packages](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/11_aa.htm) are what other systems call [namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace).

You have to use [`load`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_load.htm) or [`require`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_provid.htm) - or whatever the documentation instructs you to do - to make the desired functionality (including the packages and functions) available.

Once the code is loaded into Lisp, you can use [`list-all-packages`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_list_a.htm) to see which packages are now available.

Comment: I know, I'm doing that. The file is getting loaded but if I call a function defined in that file it's not recognized. So I was trying to prefix the package name onto the function but don't know how to get from the string to something I can use as a package name.

Comment: are you running in [modern mode](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/clisp.html#opt-modern) (non-case-converting)?